# ElasticSearch filters not returning results... Syntax issue?

Tags: grails, lucene, elasticsearch, filtering

I have elastic search documents which looks like following

```
{
_index: ecw
_type: grails.gorm.tests.Person
_id: Nb0tHzNDRtq3-rGSO3yVTw
_score: 1
_source: {
firstName: Bart
lastName: Simpson
age: 0
pets: [ ]
}
}
{
_index: ecw
_type: grails.gorm.tests.Person
_id: RxD7mGsvR3i5LT52MAdSLA
_score: 1
_source: {
firstName: Bob
lastName: Builder
age: 0
pets: [ ]
}
}
{
_index: ecw
_type: grails.gorm.tests.Person
_id: rJMEbBqeRcqx3K0HtfGrLg
_score: 1
_source: {
firstName: Bart
lastName: Simpson
age: 9
pets: [ ]
}
}
```

But when I run[post] the following filter on localhost:9200/ecw/grails.gorm.tests.Person/_search using head it returns nothing. Any thoughts?

```
{
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "lastName": "Simpson"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that's not the right way to use `and`. It expects a list of filters directly, i.e. `{"and": [ {"term": ...} ]}`. (Also, see http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/)

Furthermore, the `term` filter does not do any text processing/analysis. When you index the document, `Simpson` has probably been lowercased to `simpson` (amongst other things).

Therefore, you'll need to filter on `{ "term": { "lastName": "Simpson" } }`.

Lastly, you should only use `filter` on the search object if you want both facets and hits, but don't want the filter to affect the facets. In all other cases, you want to use the `filtered`-query.

To summarize, this is what you'd end up with:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "lastName": "simpson"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a runnable example: https://www.found.no/play/gist/d608591254288783cd0d

Comment: Wow thank you so much, my filter was created via ES java client. Only reducing the lastname to lowercase made it work! Thanks